# TeamCity failure condition compares branch build with some outdated branch

Tags: teamcity, code-coverage

We have set up TeamCity' "failure conditions" to fail build if code coverage metric is bad. The exact condition is to fail build in case code coverage metric has dropped down by several percents.

Sometimes we build a branch which is building for the first time. These are basically release branches. We build them once.

The problem is that TeamCity fails while building new branches. It says, code coverage is bad.

**In logs I see that TeamCity cannot find previous build for my branch**. Indeed,  it needs some previous build to compare code coverage and cannot find it because the branch is new. And as a result **it is using some "anchor" branch for comparison**.

"Anchor" branch is some old outdated branch which has bigger code coverage. So the evaluation of condition is correct.

The problem is that in case I am building a first build of some branch I expect one of the folowing behaviours:

1. disable code coverage metrics which need previous build which is missing
2. use some meaningfull "anchor" build to compare with, not some outdated build selected by some unclear to me way.

How can I fix it?

Comment: If you don't get an answer here it might be worth trying the community support forums for TeamCity, the staff keep an eye on there too: https://teamcity-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics

Answer (score 2):

People on TeamCity forum helped me with the answer.

It turned out that TeamCity is trying to find some previous build of the branch we want to build to compare metrics with current build. In case previous build is not found **it takes some build from *default branch*.**. In our case it was some branch from another release and we were surprise to see that comparison of metrics.

The solution for new branches is either to make default branch some test branch with zero metrics so that new build always has better metrics, or just turn off metrics each time a new branch is build.

Comment: You could also create multiple VCS roots that have different default branches and branch specifications

Comment: Strangely, I had an assembly compared with zero metrics and still fell

[08:25:08]Cannot find Latest finished build, branch filter: 0.3.0 to calculate metric 'number of inspection warnings' for branch 0.3.0
[08:25:08]Will try to find the anchor build in default branch
[08:25:08]Build stopped: Number of inspection warnings 1496 is more than 1% more than 0 in build #4
[08:25:08]Build failure condition: Anchor value for number of inspection warnings is taken from <latest finished build>. 
Fail and stop build if number of inspection warnings is 1% more than the anchor value